# Adding html file to div tag jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add html page to `<div>` tag using jQuery. I tried using load, get function but that did not work. Any advice how this can work?

I am learning and working on `turn.js` with just some basic knowledge of jQuery, please advise.

I am using jQuery 3.1

```
 <div id="flipbook">
      <div class="hard"> Turn.Js </div>
      <div class="hard"></div>
      <div id="page1"> </div>
      <div> Page 2 </div>
      <div> Page 3 </div>
      <div> Page 4 </div>
      <div class="hard"></div>
      <div class="hard"></div>
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#flipbook").turn({
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        autoCenter: true
    });

    $(function () {
       $.get("page1.html", function(data) {               
           $("#page1").append(data);
       });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Are there any error getting thrown in the console? What is the network tab returning for the `get` request?

Comment: jquery.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/me//page1.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.     This error i found in network tab same i tried in Edge / IE , same issue , i dont have firefox

Comment: I see what the problem is, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10752078/1179430

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are getting data back from `page1.html`, try:

```
$.get("page1.html", function(data) {
    $("#page1").html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It was not importing data due to file path was starting with file:/// .. once i installed lamp it started working ! Thanks